# Acquisition fee is haram

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam

[image]

Is this haram in Islam that are shown in above picture by circle?

Comment: Why should it be? Explain!

Comment: I am doing a fitness course in kilo fit academy website . After finishing the course I can use their  app to help the client about nutrition and fitness. So if I bring clients  by marketing to kilo fit app then they will take 15% platform fee from earnings. And if the kilo fit give me client then also they will take 15% fee for acquisition. I want to know that is this haram

Answer (score 0):

Business and trade is not haram in Islam; however how a business carries out its business can be sunnat or haram depending how business is carried out. One ought to carry out due diligence checks.

For example, a business advertising that its fees are transparent is sunnat; however, one would expect that anyway, which suggests that the trader knows that in this line of business, fees are charged in a non-transparent manner and this is likely to be in the majority, otherwise he would not need to make this a unique selling point.

But one needs to be careful - for example, a vulture fund is haram whether or not its fees are transparent or not.

Comment: What you will say about this. Is this haram or halal

Comment: @Sahanaz: Rationality in Islam is sunnat; but you're making no sense here.